# Implementing a simple spin lock given some instruction

Tags: c, operating-system

For instance if have the following code which is some If set then clear and performs atomic in following manner. This is simple C code.

```
int IfSetThenClear(int * ptr)
{
    int actual = *ptr;
    if(actual== 1)
    *ptr = 0;
    return actual;
}
```

Now i want to use this given instruction implement a spin lock
how would i achieve it? i am not looking for any workign code
i just want to learn so even pesudo code that can explain will help a lot
i am new to OS.

Comment: This kind of thing has to be done in assembly language or a language (such as BLISS) that allows access to individual instructions. To make this work correctly you need an interlocked test and set instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably a zero means the lock is held.

You'd do something like:

```
int spinlock_flag; // shared flag

while (IfSetThenClear(&spinlock_flag) == 1)) {} // returns 1 if it was locked and is now 0 which i means i hold the lock.

do_something();

spinlock_flag = 1; // unlocked.
```

You know you need to use an atomic compare and swap operation for this to make sense outside in real life?

This might help - some code I posted to code review a few months ago when I was working on my toy operating system.  The code posted works and there are some great responses.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84148/spinlock-for-c-kernel-with-x86-asm